# Remove string literals from elements inside an array

Tags: swift

Please guys i need to parse a string to look like these in swift

`"[{"question":9, "answer":25}", "question\":10, "answer":27}]"`

where the index and value are dynamically gotten from a loop. I was able to get to these

`["{\"question\":9, \"answer\":25}", "{\"question\":10, \"answer\":27}", "{\"question\":11, \"answer\":29}", "{\"question\":12, \"answer\":33}", "{\"question\":13, \"answer\":37}"]`

so i have tried this

> ```
>   for i in 0..<answersForQuestionInPage.count{
>
>     let questions = answersForQuestionInPage[i] as Answer
>
>
>     do {
>     let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(questions)
>     // 2
>     let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
>     answers.append(string)
>      print("This is the main value \(string)")
>
>     } catch{
>
>     }
> }
> ```

this still gives me an array with this format

> ["{\"question\":9, \"answer\":25}", "{\"question\":10,
>   \"answer\":27}", "{\"question\":11, \"answer\":29}",
>   "{\"question\":12, \"answer\":33}", "{\"question\":13,
>   \"answer\":37}"]

with the object

> "{\"question\":9, \"answer\":25}"
>   still wrapped in a string liteal " " what i want is for this return array to be in this format
>
> [{"question":9, "answer":25}, {"question":10,
>   "answer":27}, {"question":11, "answer":29},
>   "{"question":12, "answer":33}, {"question":13,
>   "answer":37}]

Comment: This is a json what you just got, you need to parse json. You can find lots of example about it.  You don't need to remove anything like / or " . you should parse json and you will achieve what you need.  Look at the Rob answer.

Comment: i have updated the question i hope am clear enough

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the whole thing, but you said you need to parse the `String`, but I think you meant `JSON`. So, you can do it like this and get the values. Do let me know if it is what you needed, otherwise please add clarity in your question and I will edit and update my answer accordingly.

```
struct Quiz: Decodable {
 let question, answer: Int
}

private func fetchQuizzes() {

  //After getting the data from API, you can do this

  guard let quiz = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Quiz].self,from: data) else { print("Unable to parse"); return }

  print(quiz)
  print(quiz.first?.answer) //First Answer

}
```

Comment: so i have array of an object  say answer object that has this pattern [Quiz]. Want to submit this data to an endpoints and what the endpoint expects the data to look like this [{"question":9, "answer":25}", {"question":10, "answer":27}] in string format not array

Comment: Please show me what you have tried so far, it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Rob said before, you have a JSON here. 
Using Robs code you decode the given JSON and create an array of Quiz objects (Robs struct).

You can now work with that array and transform it to your needs.